# Is there a clean way to return a FilePathResult and delete the on-disk file afterwards?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class that uses an external process to create a file and that gets returned as a download result, at which point I want to delete the file from the server. I generally like to avoid temporary on-disk files, but in this case it's impossible to avoid.

---

I initially tried to implement this using a Dispose method:

```
public class SetupFile : IDisposable 
{
    /// <summary>Local file path</summary>
    public string LocalFilePath { get; set; }
    /// <summary>Filename to present to user</summary>
    public string DownloadFilename { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(LocalFile);
    }
}
```

The controller code creates and operates on this file and then returns the result as a `FilePathResult`:

```
public class DownloadController : Controller 
{
    public SetupFileGenerator Generator { get; set; } 
    public DigitalSignatureTool Signer { get; set; }

    [HttpPost, Route("/download")]
    public ActionResult Download(InstallParams params) 
    {
        using (SetupFile file = Generator.Generate(params)) {
        {   
            Signer.Sign(file.LocalFilePath); // note: requires a local path!

            return new FilePathResult(file.LocalFilePath, "application/octet-stream")
            {
                FileDownloadName = file.DownloadFilename
            };
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that `Generator` and `Signer` are being inserted to the Controller via Dependency Injection, and to maintain separation of concerns I didn't want `SetupFileGenerator` to depend on `DigitalSignatureTool`. Important bit about this is that I do need the file on-disk for `Signer.Sign` to run -- hence `Generator.Generate()` can't just return a Stream).

The problem here is that `FilePathResult` only sends the file when [its `WriteFile()` method](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FilePathResult.cs#L22) gets called later in the processing pipeline, which means my `SetupFile.Dispose()` method has already been called.

---

I think my next step would be to do one of two things:

- Implement a new class that derives from `FilePathResult` but also deletes the file after it's sent
- Refactor my code so that instead of `SetupFile` having a property `string LocalFilePath`, it has `MemoryStream FileContents`

However, this seems like it would be a fairly common pattern, so before I go reinventing the wheel, is there a best practice for implementation? Anything to specifically watch out for?

Comment: you should separate the two processes because file management can be a pita.  sometimes the files get locked and cause problems that you don't want to manage here.  you should put that management into a simple service that can run whenever you like

Comment: You could just use a class inherited from `MemoryStream` on which you would have overriden the `Dispose()` method ?

Comment: @phillip Good point: there are probably a few reasons it can fail, that require a periodic out-of-band cleanup operation. But this would need to also take into account that it can't delete in-use files (eg, stuff that's currently being downloaded).. Doable.

Comment: Personally I like to contain as many related things in one viewmodel as possible.  Consider this: You could have a viewmodel named VMDownLoadController.  In that view model would be the properties:   SetupFileGenerator , DigitalSignatureTool as well as InstallParams.  Put all the logic into that VM and allow it to control workflow.  This may help to resolve state issues because the VM will control creation and disposals.  That viewmodel only needs two methods the null CTOR and the POST method if a callback is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OnResultExecuted method runs after the response is written.  You can override that with an ActionFilterAttribute.

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        string filePath = (filterContext.Result as FilePathResult).FileName;
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    } 
}
```

Just decorate your method as follows:

```
[DeleteFile]
[HttpPost, Route("/download")]
public ActionResult Download(InstallParams params) 
{
    using (SetupFile file = Generator.Generate(params))
    {   
        Signer.Sign(file.LocalFilePath);

        return new FilePathResult(file.LocalFilePath, "application/octet-stream")
        {
            FileDownloadName = file.DownloadFilename
        };
    }
}
```